# Primary focal length of a cassegrain telescope

Tags: astronomy, telescopes

How to choose the primary mirror focal length of a cassegrain telescope if your focal ratio is known.

Comment: use http://www.astrophoto.sk/wp-content/uploads/cassegrain_e_main.html

Comment: Thank you very much